# How will the force act outside the stick?

Tags: vectors, physics, classical-mechanics, statics

**Scenario 1:**

[image]

Here, $P>Q$. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick. The resultant acts to the right of $\vec{P}$ as $P>Q$.

**Scenario 2:**

[image]

Here, $P>Q$ also. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick. Now, the problem here is that as $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ act at the two ends of the bar/stick, there is no place left to the right of $\vec{P}$. So, where will the resultant of magnitude $(P-Q)$ act?

Comment: Crossposted from [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/699891/260477)

Comment: The resultant force is not actual force which needs physical point of application. $(P-Q)a = P l/2 + Q l/2 \Rightarrow a=\frac{P+Q}{P-Q}\frac{l}{2}$. $a$ is distance from O to action line of resultant.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu See this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/699896/260477). There $b>a$, so the force will actually act outside the bar! How is that possible?! "The resultant force is not actual force which needs physical point of application." - could you please elaborate on this, sir?

Comment: I repeat: The resultant force is not actual force, resultant force does not need physical point of application. The resultant force of P and Q forces is force $R=P-Q$ located outside the stick. This resultant force R can be used to replace P and Q forces with one force. There can be additional force in axis, but this force does no influence the fact, that two forces P and Q can be replaced with one force R located outside the stick.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410108/768162) a question about this topic. I linked your comment in that post. I figured you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Here, $P>Q$. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick.

It's more useful and natural, and less confusing/misleading, to label vectors with their names $(\mathbf Q,\mathbf P,\mathbf P+\mathbf Q)$ rather than their lengths $(|\mathbf Q|,|\mathbf P|,|\mathbf P|-|\mathbf Q|).$

Likewise, lengths $(|\mathbf Q|,|\mathbf P|)$ ought to be notationally distinguished from points $(Q,P,O).$

> **Scenario 2:**
>
> the problem here is that as $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ act at the two ends of the bar/stick, there is no place left to the right of $\vec{P}$. So, where will the resultant of magnitude $(P-Q)$ act?

*Assume* that the rotation axis passes through $O,$ that all forces are vertical, and that $\mathbf Q\ne\mathbf0.$ Then the resultant force-torque $(\mathbf P+\mathbf Q),$ which has the combined effect of $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q,$ indeed has a vertical line of action on $\mathbf P$'s right. Obviously, this resultant force cannot be physically implemented.

(Circling back to my opening point: “resultant of magnitude $(P−Q)$” is confusing to parse, unlike “resultant force with magnitude $(P-Q)$” or simply “resultant force $\mathbf P+\mathbf Q$”. Still, since we're already using unboldfaced capital letters to denote points, $|\mathbf P|$ is better than $P$ to denote $\mathbf P$'s length.)

Comment: "that all forces are vertical"- are you just stating the obvious from my figure? I drew them vertically, so why are you again assuming that **P** and **Q** are vertical?

Comment: If it [looks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410589/simple-quadratic-function-but-cant-understand-the-question/4410610#comment9230951_4410610) like an equilateral triangle, is it [then](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699362/what-is-the-significance-of-sliding-a-force-vector/699373#comment1567740_699373) an equilateral triangle?

Comment: [will disappear this comment] Developing metacognition, and habits of mind like good reasoning and unambiguous communication, are the most valuable aspects of education. With these, recognising fallacies and avoiding unwarranted assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The $P-Q$ resultant is in the incorrect position.

Because the rod is subjected to both a net force and a net couple a way of considering the situation is as follows.

[image]

Add forces $Q'$ and $Q''$ acting at the centre of mass $O$ of the same magnitude as force $Q$ as shown in the diagram and repeat by adding forces $P'$ and $P''$ acting at the centre of mass $O$ of the same magnitude as force $P$ as shown in the diagram.

Forces $Q$ and $Q'$ constitute a couple magnitude $Qq$ in an anticlockwise direction and forces $P$ and $P''$ constitute a couple magnitude $Pp$ also in an anticlockwise direction, so the net torque on the rod is $Qq+Pp$ anticlockwise.

The net force acting at the centre of mass of the rod is $P-Q$ and this is just as true for your second diagram.