# How to replace these two forces with one force?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

[image: ![enter image description here]

[*Please also refer to the **EDIT** appended below.*]

Here, $P>Q$. $O$ is the center of mass of the rigid and uniform bar/stick.

As $P>Q$, the resultant is situated to the right of $\vec{P}$ and is parallel to $\vec{P}$. The magnitude of the resultant is $P-Q$.

To convince you that the figure is correct, I'll do some math to prove it.

Let us obtain the sum of torques about the center of mass,

[image]

$$(P-Q)b=Pa+Qa$$

$$b=\frac{P+Q}{P-Q}a$$

$$b=fa\ \left[\text{Let $f=\frac{P+Q}{P-Q}$}\right]$$

As $P>Q$, $f>1$, and $b>a$ [see edit below]. So, the correct figure will be,

[image]

I hope you're satisfied that the figure is correct.

**My comments:**

Is it possible to replace $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ with a single force? I mean practically, not theoretically. From the figure, we can see that the resultant force is outside the bar. In other words, $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ can be replaced by a force of magnitude $P-Q$, which will act outside the bar. This may be possible theoretically; however, this is not possible practically as the resultant force will be acting on literally nothing as it is outside the bar. Therefore, I conclude that it is impossible to replace $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ with a single force practically. Theoretically, it is possible, but practically, no.

**My question:**

1. Can $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ be replaced by a single force? Is my conclusion correct?

---

These may help you to answer this question:

1. [Comment by @Ivan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409056/how-will-the-force-act-outside-the-stick?noredirect=1#comment9224729_4409056)
2. [Answer by @Farcher](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/699905/260477)

---

This question was posted with the help of [@Eli](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/196140/eli).

---

---

**EDIT (from a now-deleted answer)**

Clarifications:

- **Point $O$ is not affixed.**
- $\vec Q\ne\mathbf0.$

Correction:

- Regarding the mathematics in the second block, $f>1$ not merely because $P>Q,$ but because $P>Q>0.$

Comment: Crossposted from [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700098/260477).

Comment: Your conclusion seems fine to me

Comment: Notice that you made sure they weren't equal so this process of replacing multiple forces with a single force such that net torque about O and net force are the same will break down as you push smaller net force farther and farther out as $P -> Q^+$. Also note that you only have preserved those two pieces of information so you can't just replace it for another calculation like torque around another point.

Comment: @AHusain What do you mean by $P->Q^+$? Do you mean $P\to Q^{+}$?

Comment: Crossposted to [ESE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50300/37352)

Comment: To see the problem from practical point of view, you should add practical problem statement. If point O is fixed, then only important part of resultant force is torque, which makes it possible to change application point.If you want for some practical need (I don't know what it may be) to preserve both torque and value of resultant force, you can extend stick with additional rigidly bound section.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Firstly, point O isn't fixed. Secondly, if we extend the stick, the center of mass will change. If the center of mass changes, the system will change completely. Then none of our old calculations will work. We will have to then find a new resultant for $P$ and $Q$, so I don't understand how we can extend the stick without changing the system entirely and negating all our previous calculations. Could you please give me some pointers, sir?

Comment: If the problem is only in location of the center of mass, you can extend stick at both sides. As for your theoretical point: there is not always direct way of using theoretical concept (resultant force) in practical problem. But in most cases, it can be useful. You need to make practical problem statement and you can see if this concept is useful for this problem or not.

Comment: Why not just a(P+Q)?  BTW O (CG) is fixed.  Start by drawing your diagram accurately and *to scale*.  a(P+Q) will be torque.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni No O is not fixed. That's one of the premises of my setup.

Comment: Then every time you move O, torques must be recalculated.  If the item is rapidly rotating, don't forget *drag*.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.